# Importing SQL Server data as Numeric

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula

I am importing data from SQL Server to Excel with VBA. I have access to the SQL database. My issue is that it is being read as text in formulas, I don't get an error message and arithmetic works. By this I mean if I write:

```
=AVG(A1:A4) the answer is #DIV/0
=(A1+A2+A3+A4)/4 the answer is correct
```

I have tried all the suggested common Excel "fixes" but ideally I would simply like to avoid the issue. I understand Excel is basing the decision on the first 100 columns of data, but there are only about 20 columns of data. I have tried altering all the formatting in the worksheet to Number format but that doesn't seem to help.

I'm wondering if their is a way to change the format the data/metadata in SQL Server that would help the transfer result in Excel accepting the import as numeric data?

Comment: You need to show us *how* your exporting the data to Excel. SQL Server doesn't choose the formatting preference of the column, Excel does, so the obvious answer would be that the column has the incorrect format setting.

Comment: Hi All the columns are set to number, like I say unfortunately I've been through all the common suggested options. The only thing that seems to work is to copy and paste the values to a new sheet and then process text to columns individually, however I would prefer to not have the extra sheet. The data is being processed from a ResponseText from a CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP") ...GET....(its an addin I've inherited).

Comment: Sounds like the addin is the problem; you should be asking about that not SQL Server. Like I said, SQL Server has no way of telling Excel how to format the data, that's all up to the presentation layer; unless you're converting the numerical data to a `varchar`, but then why would you do that..?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a couple of values returned by your "addin"?

Comment: Its an XLAM that has UDFs in cells that request info from the SQL some are labels, most though will be data, and data is numeric such as 100.424 or 242.763 nothing special. It just will not run formulas with the returned data in the sheet from the UDFs.